# How can I stop my RecyclerView, populated from Firebase Database and managed by FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, from recreating deleted views?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Problem Context:

1)
I am having issues with a social media clone app, specifically with the user feed (within a recyclerView) and manipulating posts (within a ViewHolder Class).

2)
Views are populated from the Firebase Realtime Database.

3)
Creating a "post" works correctly (all information is correctly passed to Firebase and loaded into the recycler).

4)
I can delete a post from Firebase using:

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(postsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).removeValue();
```

However, if I create a new post after deleting a previous post, the previously deleted post reappears both in the database and in the recycler.

Problem Observations:

1)
It appears as though a local copy of the post is stored in an array (I didn't create an array, so there must be some default array triggered by a datasnapshot or something).

2)
If I can somehow reset this hidden array's index, I believe the problem would be solved. For every app session, the recyclerView is determined to populate as many posts as there have been in the current session. To clarify, I can make a post, reload the session, delete it, make another post, and the deleted post will not reappear.

Problem Attempts:

I have tried using

```
1) newsFeedRecycler.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
2) firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0,firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount());
3) postsViewHolder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
4) newsFeedRecycler.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
5) firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
6) firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(postsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

and more over the course of 3 days to try to effectively wipe a deleted post from the local memory as well as from Firebase.

Problem Appeal:

I am very new to Java and have learned what I know now from a hands-on approach, so there may be something missing from my understanding of the problem. I do however know that this question is not a duplicate, as I have tried virtually every solution I could find on Stack Overflow that even remotely addressed this issue. I would be super appreciative if someone would help me understand both what the problem is and how to fix it. Cheers

Comment: You asked your question in a clear way, but you have to provide some code. Mainly the `adapter code` and the `code where you create a new post`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Hasan. And, by sorting through what code was relevant to add to my question, I was able to solve my issue. I will post my solution (including code) below. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future viewers, I was actually able to solve my problem by adding a seemingly small detail (something that I had remembered seeing in another answer, but addressing a different issue). Initially, my "upload post" method looked something like this:

```
private void uploadPostInfo() {

    userReference.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();

                postsMap.put("timestamp", formattedDate);
                postsMap.put("uid",currentUserID);
                postsMap.put("postText",postText);
                postsMap.put("postImage",downloadUrlImage);
                postsMap.put("postFile",downloadUrlFile);

                postsReference.child(currentUserID + formattedDate).updateChildren(postsMap)

            }
```

This, by all means, looks correct. However, using "addValueEventListener" adds all cached values of the post. The correct way to fix this issue is to limit the listener to a single event - using `addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {` instead of `addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`.

Also for future viewers, another problem previously affecting the consistency of my app when managing posts (and making this issue appear more complex than it was) was that my post "key" was using getRef() by taking OnBindViewholder()'s "position" parameter directly from within an internal onClick() call as part of the "user feed" Activity. For example:

OnBindViewHolder: 
`protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsViewHolder postsViewHolder, final int position, @NonNull final Posts model) {`

Retrieving Key Before: `PostKey = getRef(position).getKey();`

Retrieving Key After: `PostKey = getRef(postsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();`

To my understanding, this is required because `position` can only take a new value after rebinding if `position` is used directly to determine the post key value, however `(postsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` can retrieve the position without rebinding.